# Aura iteration too show value in two columns

Tags: iteration

i need to show in two grids how to use aura iteration to do it.

suppose list is like ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,kl,mn
then the ui should values like

```
   ab cd
   ef gh
   ij kl
   mn
```

please suggest if you have something in mind.

Comment: ab cd<br>ef gh<br>ij kl<br>mn  show values in two columns using iteration or some other

Answer (score 2):

first create a wrapper list in you code or a list of list. In the inner list fill only two values.

```
<!-- BASIC GRID EXAMPLE -->
<div class="slds-grid">
  <div class="slds-col slds-size--4-of-6">Column 1</div>
  <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-6">Column 2</div>
  <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-6">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Now using the [LDS](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_design_system/lightning-design-system3) Grid system and nested Aura iteration tag you will get your desired UI.